# why does SWIG appear to corrupt contents of a member class?

Tags: python, swig

When a class contains a pointer to another, the contents of the other class appear to be inconstistently reported by SWIG.  Here is the smallest reproducible example (SSCCE):

Config.h:

```
class Config
{
    int debug;      
public:
    void showDebug(void);
};

class ConfigContainer
{
    Config *config; 
public:
    ConfigContainer(Config *);
    void showDebug(void);
};
```

Config.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Config.h"

using namespace std;

void Config::showDebug(void) {
    cout << "debug address: " << &debug << " contents: " << debug << endl;
}

ConfigContainer::ConfigContainer(Config *cfg)
{
        config= cfg;
}

void ConfigContainer::showDebug(void)
{
    config->showDebug();
}
```

Now when I translate this with SWIG to Python, I get this:

```
>>>>c = ConfigContainer(Config())
>>>>c.showDebug()
debug address: 0xabf380 contents: 11586464
>>> c.showDebug()
debug address: 0xabf380 contents: 11067216
```

When I run this sequence in C++ alone, the contents reported are the same.  But with SWIG, even though the address is the same, SWIG appears to corrupt the value inside that address.

The responder says, it is because `Config *config` member of ConfigContainer, has reference count decremented in Python, once `showDebug()` is called.

How do I tell SWIG, to tell Python to leave `config` member alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a lifetime issue.

If a pointer the object you pass to a function is going to be kept stored somewhere you need to inform about this the Python runtime by incrementing the reference counter.

If you don't do this then the object will be possibly destroyed after the first call is terminated and so your `config` pointer is actually pointing to memory that Python thinks is reusable.

What you are observing is that the memory has been actually reused for other objects (so you see the content changing).

In cpython object lifetime is managed using reference counters (with a separate collection algorithm to solve the problem of reference loops). Each object has a counter of how many other objects are pointing to it and this counter must be kept correct at every use.

If you pass to a function an object and the function code stores the pointer to the object somewhere then it should also increment the reference counter for the pointed object. If it fails to notify the object of the new stored reference the problem is that the object could be destroyed leaving a dangling pointer to unallocated (or later reused) memory.

The opposite problem (incrementing the reference too much) is a memory leak, because Python memory manager will not reclaim the object memory even if no one is using it if the reference counter is greater than zero.

See http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/refcounting.html and related documentation.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I am just not familliar with Python enough.  Well, I am not actually passing a pointer to any method at all.  Do you mean, I should "increment the reference counter" of member "config" of ConfigContainer??  How do I do that?

Comment: Well yes... I know.  I already found the documentation you are referring to.  Thank you Sir :)  What I am not getting yet, is, how do I do this from Python command line... I can't use those Py... functions (well, not easily).  All I have, is C++, and Python command line, and SWIG which is supposed to translate between the two.  I guess, I have to use the Py... functions in the SWIG interface code.  This is not going to be pleasant...

Comment: @MarkGaleck: SWIG is indeed pretty low-level. For interfacing C++ code we found SIP (http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download) much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

When Python creates your `Config` object, it doesn't hold a permanent reference to it.  Your ConfigContainer class just holds a simple pointer, so even in C++, if you don't keep the object alive the ConfigContainer won't know about it.

The following line has Python creating a temporary `Config` object that is destroyed when the line completes:

```
c = ConfigContainer(Config())
```

You can see this if you add footprinting to the constructors and destructors, like I did below:

```
>>> import x
>>> c = x.ConfigContainer(x.Config())
__cdecl Config::Config(void)
__cdecl ConfigContainer::ConfigContainer(class Config *)
__cdecl Config::~Config(void)
```

So now ConfigContainer holds a destroyed pointer.  The simple solution is to hold on to a reference to `Config` until you are done.

```
>>> import x
>>> c = x.Config()
__cdecl Config::Config(void)
>>> cc = x.ConfigContainer(c)
__cdecl ConfigContainer::ConfigContainer(class Config *)
```

The complicated solution is to implement reference counting (see [6.25 C++ reference counted objects - ref/unref feature](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_ref_unref)).

Another solution is to use SWIG's support for `std::shared_ptr` by changing the container:

```
class ConfigContainer
{
    std::shared_ptr<Config> config; 
public:
    ConfigContainer(std::shared_ptr<Config>&);
    ~ConfigContainer();
    void showDebug(void);
};
```

The following is required in the interface file:

```
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(Config)          // This instantiates the template for SWIG
```

Now `Config` will be reference counted:

```
>>> import x
>>> cc = x.ConfigContainer(x.Config())
__cdecl Config::Config(void)
__cdecl ConfigContainer::ConfigContainer(class std::shared_ptr<class Config> &)
```

`ConfigContainer` now holds a reference to `Config`.  Destroying the container destroys the last reference to `Config`:

```
>>> del cc
__cdecl ConfigContainer::~ConfigContainer(void)
__cdecl Config::~Config(void)
```

But if Python has its own reference only the container is destroyed when Python is done with it:

```
>>> c = x.Config()
__cdecl Config::Config(void)
>>> cc = x.ConfigContainer(c)
__cdecl ConfigContainer::ConfigContainer(class std::shared_ptr<class Config> &)
>>> del cc
__cdecl ConfigContainer::~ConfigContainer(void)
>>> del c
__cdecl Config::~Config(void)
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I already adopted the previous answer when you wrote this.  I appreciate your efforts to help me.